# Docker volume not used with Redis (mount does show up with inspect)

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

**My final conclusion is that I wasn't able to set the `/c/users/...` location because it wasn't shared in "Docker".**

[image]

**After this I was able to *see* the `/c/users/..` directory in *all* my container instances. I was then able to use the `-v` flag with this directory on every instance basically writing files to my host machine.
What I still don't get is that I don't think I'm actually using `volumes` at the moment... But it works...**

---

I'm trying to have my Docker-hosted Redis instance to persist its data but the mounted volume doesn't seem to be used. I was using Docker with VirtualBox/boot2docker where the composition worked, however I have since moved to Docker for Windows where the compose file still works, but I'm not sure about the `volumes` property.

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
vq-redis:
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
   - "6379:6379"
  volumes:
    - /c/users/r/.docker/data/redis/data:/data
```

It doesn't matter if I add or remove the `volumes` definition, because it will always show something like this with `docker inspect`:

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Name": "40791b26771b5d62778d85b0ef24e74e516f95d32cf217424232ce8f8a1b8c6f",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/40791b26771b5d62778d85b0ef24e74e516f95d32cf217424232ce8f8a1b8c6f/_data",
            "Destination": "/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

Is the `volumes` property still working with Docker for Windows or am I missing a point?

**Edit:**

If I run...

```
docker run --name vq-redis -d -v //c/users/r/.docker/data/vq-redis:/data redis redis-server --appendonly yes
```

... I can see the container appearing in Kitematic and with `docker inspect` I can see a mount going to my local folder. However the local folder isn't shown in Kitematic...

[image]

**If I add data to the Redis server hosted in the container, then stop the container and start it again the data is gone.**

I tried setting the local folder manually in Kitematic. This restarts the container so it seems, but I'm unsure if the initial parameters are passed again. You say:

> "If the volumes aren't networked on run"

I guess they *were actually networked on run* as seen in the console.

[image]

Still, I can add data to the Redis instance hosted in the container. But as soon as I restart the container it's gone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. I assume you didn't get any errors (e.g., permission issues, etc.) and that you are removing old builds before rebuilding. Does the "/var/lib/docker/volumes/4079..." directory get created?
You could try using double leading slashes on Windows, which was a work-around for some versions:

```
volumes:
    - //c/users/r/.docker/data/redis/data:/data
```

Redis wouldn't have anything to do with the volume not being created but have you tried other services or even basic `docker create -v ...` or `docker run -v ...`?

UPDATE:
There may be some gaps in your understanding of how Docker works that may be getting in the way here.

If you do `docker run --name some-redis -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes` it will create a volume similar to the one you have in your `docker inspect` output. Clearly you don't have a `/var/lib/docker/volumes/...` directory on your Windows machine -- that's in the VM docker host (e.g., boot2docker). How you get to the Docker host volumes differs depending on a number of factors.

If the volumes aren't networked on `run`, restarting won't help. Do `docker stop some-redis && docker rm some-redis` and re-`run`.

Eg. running this command 
`docker run --name some-redis -d -v $(pwd)/data:/data redis redis-server --appendonly yes` 
should work as you expect. 
`ls ./data` => `appendonly.aof`.

It will obviously be empty at first. Destroying the container and creating a new one with the same directory will show the data is still there:

```
docker exec some-redis echo "set bar baz" | redis-cli
docker stop some-redis
docker rm some-redis
docker run --name some-redis2 -d -v $(pwd)/data:/data redis redis-server --appendonly yes
docker exec some-redis2 echo "get bar" | redis-cli
```

=> "baz"

(the previous value for "bar" set in the destroyed container).

If this doesn't work for you there could be some issues specific to your environment -- perhaps try a Vagrant-based solution or beta Docker or a native Linux host.

Comment: I tried the most basic example from the hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/): Start with persistent storage: `docker run --name some-redis -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes`. I can see the container in Kitematic where I'm also able to make sure that the port is exposed and that the `/data` folder is pointing to a local folder in my user directory (both I had to do manually and restarted the container). But I don't see any data appearing when I fill the database (checked through RedisDesktopManager). Nothing is being persisted when I stop the container...

Comment: @Idg: I actually got it working, but I don't think I'm using volumes... See updated question.